# How can we spot an XElement value that's CData?

Tags: xml, parsing, cdata

I have some xml in which a specific element, let's call it dave might either be:

```
<dave>A Normal Value</dave>
```

or

```
<dave><![CDATA[A CData Value!]]></dave>
```

When I'm parsing it I would like to be able to test whether the retrieved value is CDATA or not. How would I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have

```
XElement xe = XElement.Parse("<dave>something</dave>");
```

then

```
xe.FirstNode.NodeType
```

will be `Text` or `CDATA` respectively in your examples. Node that `xe.FirstNode` can be null if there is no content.